# Remove null values and empty maps from Map of Maps (to undefined depth) in Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I need to iterate through a Map of Maps (which may themselves contain Maps to an unknown depth) and remove any null values. In the case of all values being null (leaving an empty map) then then entire map should be removed.

To clarify, looking at myMap below I wish to remove b, e, and j because they are null, but also remove i as when j is removed it contains an empty map, and k which is an empty map to start.

I can use findAll to remove the top level nulls (as shown in the first assert) but wondered if there was a Groovy way to resolve the second assert.

```
    Map myMap = [ a : 1
                , b : null
                , c : [ d : 1
                      , e : null
                      , f : [ g : 1 
                            , h : 2 ]
                      , i : [ j : null ]
                      , k : [:] ] ]

    assert [a:1, c:[d:1, e:null, f:[g:1, h:2], i:[j:null], k:[:]]] == myMap.findAll(){ it.value != null }     


    assert [a:1, c:[d:1, f:[g:1, h:2]]] == '<<SOME CODE>>'
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be simpler ways, but you can use collectEntries to recurse through the map values, and then use findAll to remove the empty ones, ie:

```
def deepPrune = { Map map ->
    map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v instanceof Map ? owner.call(v) : v]}
       .findAll { k, v -> v }
}

assert deepPrune(myMap) == ['a':1, 'c':['d':1, 'f':['g':1, 'h':2]]]
```

Or as a method:

```
def deepPrune(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v instanceof Map ? deepPrune(v) : v]}
       .findAll { k, v -> v }
}
```

Note: the above deepPrune method also removes values with false!

If you do not want to remove false values use:

```
Map deepPrune(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v instanceof Map ? deepPrune(v) : v]}
       .findAll { k, v -> v || v == false } as Map
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you that works perfectly. One question I have is... Is there any benefit from having this as a closure rather than a recursively called method?

Comment: None...  I added a method version to my answer ;-)

Comment: This will also remove values of empty string or zero which may not be desirable.

Comment: In addition to what @verglor has mentioned, `false` values and empty collections will be removed, too (see [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)).

Answer (score 0):

tim_yates deepPrune method got me close but was a little too aggressive.  It was deep pruning a hash of all empty [:], [], false, and 0:

```
// Deep Prune a hash of all empty [:], [] preserving false, and 0
def deepPrune(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v ->
       [k, v instanceof Map ? deepPrune(v) : v]
    }.findAll { k, v -> v != [:] && v != [] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can go slightly further, than @DaxGames suggested, while still not as aggressive as the accepted answer.

```
// this deep prune leaves zeros, and false values intact
// while removing nulls and empty strings along with empty Maps and Lists
def deepPrune(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v ->
        [k, v instanceof Map ? deepPrune(v) : v]
    }.findAll { k, v -> v != [:] && v != [] && v != null && v != ''}
}
```